# Getting error in FloatingActionButton (Scaffold) Flutter Ubuntu

Tags: flutter, scaffold

I am new to flutter started just right now, was following one tutorial, even though I copied exactly same code it's giving me error. Here is my **code.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App Bar'),
        centerTitle: true
      ), //Appbar
      
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello!'),
      ), //Body
      
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Click')
      ), //FloatingActionButton

    ), //Scaffold
));
```

And here is the **ERROR!**

```
lib/main.dart:15:49: Error: Required named parameter 'onPressed' must be
provided.
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                                                ^
/home/hackytech/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/fl
oating_action_button.dart:100:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the
arguments don't match.
  const FloatingActionButton({
```

Please can anyone explain me what's the problem and it will be excellent if I get a tip for learning flutter or any source as I am new to this framework

Thank you :)

Comment: please read the error message. You must provide `onPressed` property to `FloatingActionButton`, You're only providing `child` parameter of the class. `onPressed` is mandatory field

Comment: Well sorry bro @HasilT AS I clearly mentioned I am new to this, I don't know what that error says. Thanks for informing. I didn't knew that its important field. In that Youtube channel he ran that code without that parameter and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onPressed` method is required for [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

Therefore, while using  [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) you need to call [`onPressed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/onPressed.html).

> VoidCallback? onPressed

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {}, //you can also pass null here
  child: Text("text"),
),
```

While you like to have `Text` widget on `floatingActionButton:` you can simply use `Text`(or any other widget) widget there.

`floatingActionButton: Text("text"),`

Answer (score 1):

pass on pressed property

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Click'),
        onPressed: () {
              print("click");
            }
      ), //FloatingActionButton
```

Answer (score 0):

`floatingActionButton` requires `onPressed` attached.
and Need to be within `Scaffold` Widget.

SO

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
     onPressed: () { //anything you need to do after tap  },
    tooltip: 'Shopping Bag',
    child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
  ),
```